# What is the best solution for a free partition recovery?

Tags: macos, mac, partition, external-disk

Recently I accidentally partitioned my Seagate Backup Drive (1 TB) not knowing that everything would be wiped off (silly me). I am now in shock knowing that my files are somewhat gone.

I have tried many such as *Wondershare* or *EaseUS* but all require me to pay upfront, the trials do no good whatsoever. Is there any 100% free software for recovering partitioned external drives? I just need an answer.

I do realize the risk of putting a wide variety question on here, but I am in dire need of getting my files back and would just like some experience on the matter.

Comment: If I might add (without the intention to be slanderous), Wondershare seems to market their software under many different domains ([easeUS](http://www.easeus.com), [iphone-data-recovery](http://iphone-data-recovery.com) et cetera) in addition to their primary [Wondershare](https://www.wondershare.com) page. Of course, this is only unsubstantiated speculation, but I thought I'd share my two cents' of experience having gone through something similar, eventually noting similarities between the software (and webpages) that these "independent" organisations create.

Answer (score 2):

Data Rescue from ProSoft* works, it has a trial and no-cost limited-recovery options. You won't get the whole volume recovered by freeware.

It is unlikely you will get everything back, and if you are still using that drive your recovery percent goes down every hour as files get overwritten. Also unlikely you will get filenames back, just a great big folder of "Recovered File 000238.txt"

Of course you need a different drive to recover things to - no sane recovery program touches the original volume.

Just for comparison, if you want to let the pros at DriveSavers handle the recovery the bill will start at $1000.

- prosofteng.com, NOT datarescue.com